# Mutable Custom Class & Descriptor confusion

Tags: python, oop, dictionary, descriptor

*I am trying to understand how exactly descriptors work, especially in conjunction with custom mutable classes.*

**A hopefully succinct abstract of my question:**

- How do I make a custom class, which will have descriptors, but will be mutable?

Now lets add some contexts and substance. I have recently been doing the Pluralsights Advanced Python course, where they introduced descriptors. Thus I am using a pattern from the course. But it does not work as I expected.

The pattern of **Descriptor**:

> *The one that I am using is quite different, but it has the same pattern just the checks it performs are more complex. But that part is
>   unittested, so I really do not expect that to be a problem, for
>   further justification read on.*

```
class DataFrameDescriptor:

    def __init__(self):
        self._instance_data = WeakKeyDictionary()

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self._instance_data[instance]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # some code which makes sure, the columns of the descriptor 
        #  stay the same
           self._instance_data[instance] = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        raise AttributeError("Cannot delete attribute")
```

The **Descripted Custom Class**:

> *Here I have again put just the scaffold of the class, to avoid unnecessary jumbo amounts of code, which the real class implements.
>   Basically, what I want is have a custom class, which implements a sort
>   of interface to a collection, which is in turn "managed/verified" by
>   the descriptor. To be more precise, I am implementing a
>   pandas.DataFrame, for which I have certain invariant settings on its
>   shape, to store certain objects, and I want my custom class to be a
>   dictionary like interface to the dataframe*

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

class MutableClass(MutableMapping):
    """ All the mutable mapping required methods are implemented and work as intended """

    descriptor = DataFrameDescriptor()

    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        df = prepare(some_dict) # prepares the dict to a dataframe
        self.descriptor = df

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # some checks about the value
        self.descriptor.loc[key] = value # value must be specific
```

Now, the explanation of what errors I have been getting:

Most of the errors revolved around the `__hash__` implementation, which makes sense since, the descriptors dict needs keys, which are hashes.
However, as I understand, implementing a `__hash__` and `__eq__`, with them having the same comparison results, is a kind of promise that the object will not mutate(change) over its runtime lifetime.
In my case this is absolutely not true.

I have implemented versions of `__hash__` and `__eq__`, which make it work, and removes the errors. However, it is basically a lie, because:

- I want to be able to compare my objects, where comparison would tell me if the information that they "hold" is identical

Hopefully, my question is detailed enough and understandable.

> A potentially rephrase is how to use Descriptors in non-hashable
>   Custom Classes. Or how to make a Descriptor which will work with a
>   non-hashable Custom Class.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what your question is at all. You say _"Most of the errors revolved around the __hash__ implementation"_, but there is no `__hash__` method anywhere in your code. Your `MutableClass` can't be instantiated because you didn't implement all the `MutableMapping` methods. You're trying to assign a dictionary to `self.descriptor`, which only accepts positive numbers. None of this makes any sense. I think it would help a great deal if you replaced this lengthy explanation with some code that showcases exactly what isn't working.

Comment: Yeah it isn't obvious to me what your issues are exactly. Your problem doesn't seem to be related to descriptors at all, rather, it is about hashable objects.

Comment: @Rawing Yeah, I forgot to mention that, all of those things are implemented. I should have been more clear.

Comment: The point was, that I would prefer not to implement the hash function, since this classes values will change over its lifetime.
The implementation I did make worked, but it hashed just some of the classes unchangable values. Not exactly ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this would be to use `property` instead of a custom descriptor class, and store the data on the instance instead of the descriptor:

```py
class Mutable(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter(self, x):
        if x <= 0:
            raise ValueError("x must be positive")
        self._x = x
```

With `property`, it's very natural to pick the name of the underlying instance attribute based on the name of the property; for example, I've made an underlying attribute named `_x` backing a property named `x`, following the standard pattern of prepending an underscore.

Things are more awkward with a custom descriptor class, because you can't hardcode the attribute name (or at least, hardcoding the attribute name causes name collision problems). It's better in Python 3.6, because `__set_name__` lets a descriptor know what attribute it's managing:

```py
class PositiveAttr:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.underlying = f'_{name}'
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return getattr(instance, self.underlying)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Attribute must be positive")
        setattr(instance, self.underlying, value)

class Mutable:
    x = PositiveAttr()
    ...
```

Otherwise, you'll have to tell the descriptor what name to use in its constructor:

```py
class PositiveAttr(object):
    def __init__(self, underlying):
        self.underlying = underlying
    ...

class Mutable(object):
    x = PositiveAttr('_x')
    ...
```

Comment: The answer was informative, the name part is not such a big problem. 
I will try out your recommendation for implementing this just as a property with a complex setter. If it works with all the other involved things, ill accept this as an answer :)

Comment: I implemented it as a descriptor because I would like to reuse and not copy the complex setter code in other classes. So I thought a custom descriptor would be the right way to go.

Comment: @SirSteel you don't have to, just define a module level function: `def _getter(self): ....` and `def _setter(self, x): ...` then *inside the class definition*, use `x = property(_getter, _setter)`

Comment: Yeah, I am trying this right now. Might be the better option. I just want to be able to reuse the setters across many modules.